# CodeIgniter - I have a public function in a controller but i don't want people requesting it via a URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, public

CodeIgniter - I have a public function in a controller but I don't want people requesting it via a URL.

**i.e., I have this**:

```
public function process_images($images) {
  ...
}
```

Which I need to be public because I am using GroceryCRUD and using a callback - setting it to protected means that GroceryCRUD won't call it using its callback.

So it looks like it has to be public. How do I declare it public but make sure that CodeIgniter doesn't call it from a URL request (i.e., if I went to *`http://site.com/images/process_images/test.jp`* it wouldn't call `::process_images('test.jpg'))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use underscore prefix:

```
public function _process_images($images) { ... }
```

This way it can remain public and codeigniter won't call it on an URL request.

Documented [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#private)